# c# find substrings - loop never ends

Tags: c#, string, substring

yet another string/substring topic:

I'm trying to write a function that looks for the substrings "id" and "imagePath" in a string that's generated from a very long text file. The characters between the 2 substrings should be written in a rich text box. I cannot see what I'm doing wrong, but the loop never ends and always prints only the first occurrence of said characters, resulting in a million lines that are identical being shown in the text box. There are at least 10 occurrences of both substrings in my file, and my code is below:

```
private void textToFind ( string file, string catalogType)
        {
            richTextBox1.Clear();
            catalogType.ToUpper();
            string contentOfFile = File.ReadAllText(file);
            contentOfFile.TrimEnd();
            int startPosition, endPosition;
            while (contentOfFile.Length > 20)
            {
                startPosition = contentOfFile.IndexOf("id");
                endPosition = contentOfFile.IndexOf("imagePath");
                if (startPosition >= 0 && endPosition > startPosition)
                {
                    startPosition = startPosition + 4;
                    endPosition = endPosition -3;
                    string dataToExtract = contentOfFile.Substring(startPosition, endPosition);
                    richTextBox1.AppendText(dataToExtract + "\r\n");
                    contentOfFile.Remove(startPosition-4, endPosition+12);
                }
                else
                { 
                    richTextBox1.AppendText("fail " + catalogType + "\r\n");
                    contentOfFile.Remove(contentOfFile.Length/2);
                }
            }
            return;
        }
```

Can anyone please share why this is not working as intended?? I think contentOfFile.Remove is not working and the main string doesn't get trimmed, but I don't understand why.

Many thanks!

Comment: This is an excellent time to become intimately familiar with the debugger. That being said, strings are immutable. You need to capture the value returned from many of those methods and act on *that*. Microsoft's documentation is also your friend.

Comment: [First look at the Visual Studio Debugger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Thanks guys! Yet another thing learned today

Comment: Debugging is an essential skill. If you have to ask questions like this regularly, you're going to have a rough go at it. Debugging is self-service.

Comment: It's also important that you read the documentation for *everything* you use. The documentation for `Remove` [clearly states](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove), *"Returns a new string in which a specified number of characters from the current string are deleted."* The fact that it returns a `string` rather than `void` should also be an indication that you need to do something with it.

Comment: One final note (from me, anyway): methods like `Remove`, operating on *"a very long text file"* wil be *extremely* costly, in terms of both memory and processing time, especially if what you're trying to do is a *search*, where the modifications you're making are thrown away in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`contentOfFile.Remove` doesn't actually modify the value of `contentOfFile` it just returns a string that has the specified portion removed.

So you need to do `contentOfFile = contentOfFile.Remove(startPosition - 4, endPostion + 12);`

and same thing with the `TrimEnd` call before the `while` loop.